# What will the SpaceX BFR booster look like?

Tags: spacex, raptor

SpaceX's next big booster is notionally known as BFR - Big F-ing Rocket [or Big Falcon Rocket]. (Like the B-52 is the BUFF - Big Ugly Fat F-er, it is a term of enderarment).

We know that it will use a cluster of Raptor engines, running on LOX/Methane.  Raptor has been changing over time but appears likely to be in the 1 Million lb thrust or higher.

We know they want it to be reusable which in their current mode of operation requires a center engine to keep thrust levels manageable for landing, so likely a cluster of 3, 5, or 9 engines.

That puts some boundaries on likely sizes of the core.

What will the BFR look like?  This question may have to evolve over time as more information is released.

Comment: Isn't the question too speculative to be answered objectively?

Comment: @DeerHunter My thinking was an answer can evolve as information is made public.

Comment: Suppose there **is** a question hidden here, but the best course IMHO would be to close it till more is revealed, and then nominate for reopening. Or delete for future undeletion. I'm still on the fence and have not cast my vote yet; probably worth a meta discussion.

Comment: In this case, i think it is too opinion based. It would be a fascinating discussion, but it is definitely going to be a discussion, and there are better places for that - the chat room or a related forum. Also, the best place to get an answer is to search for news releases. For now, there is this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_(rocket_family)#Proposed_future_concepts  and i know i read a news piece about the engine but i can't find it right now.

Comment: Too speculative, but I'd put my money on a scaled up Falcon 9 - 9 Raptors, in a ring of 8 engines around a central one. That should give them the same any-2-engines-out redundancy as Falcon 9 and similar performance in the powered descent. Even though many items will be forced to change in the scaling up, some design decisions should be preservable.

Comment: @DeerHunter It is possible the answer does not exist yet. But it will in the near future. I am willing to wait.

Comment: @geoffc and anyone else that might want to answer the question in the future and as the information becomes available, please flag the question for moderator's attention and/or vote to reopen and it will be. But I'm for the moment also joining those that voted to close with sole intention to prevent speculative or even chatty answers from new members that haven't yet _learned the ropes_ of our Q&A. Thanks for understanding!